# Is it possible to use std::make_unique in Xcode 5.1?

Tags: c++, xcode, std, c++14

Since Xcode 5.1 includes clang 3.4, it should be possible to use `std::make_unique`.
It seems to be defined in `memory.h`.

However, it needs to have `_LIBCPP_STD_VER > 11` but it is still set to 11 because of the value of `__cplusplus` macro (still `201103L`).

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As specified in the [clang website](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), you need to enable `-std=c++1y`.

Xcode does not include this option as a choice in its "C++ Language Version" option, so you will need to manually enter it. To do this, you need to go into the "Editor" menu while the project definition is open and press "Show Definitions". You should now be able to manually change the "C++ Language Dialect" option to `c++1y`:

[image: Enabling "Show Definitions"]

Comment: In Xcode 6.2, I had to use GNU++14[-std=gnu++14] to get this to work. If you select your project, you can access these settings. In 6.2, there is no ui as show above (Editor> Show Definitions).

Comment: @TimElhajj: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I don't have access to an OSX machine any more; so I can't provide a new screenshot. Feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: I could add an answer with information for 6.2, but it wouldn't really apply to this specific question. I added my note because this was the first google result for make_unique and Xcode. Hopefully it's enough to get anyone else who Googles on the right track